# find_one query returns just the fields instead of an entry

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm currently trying to use pymongo's find_one query. When I run the Mongo Shell and execute a findOne query, it get a document that is returned. However when I try using pymongo's find_one query, I always seem to get just the field names instead of an actual entry.

```
@app.route("/borough/manhattan/")
def manhattan():
    restaurantmanhattan = restaurants.find_one({'borough':'Manhattan'})
    json_restaurantmanhattan = []
    for restaurant in restaurantmanhattan:
        json_restaurantmanhattan.append(restaurant)
    json_restaurantmanhattan = json.dumps(json_restaurantmanhattan)
    return json_restaurantmanhattan
```

Once I navigate to http://0.0.0.0:5000/borough/manhattan/ I get the following:

```
["cuisine","borough","name","restaurant_id","grades","address","_id"]
```

I believe I should be seeing a document entry that meets the query that it has Manhattan listed in the borough.

I'm at a loss as to how I should be writing the query to return that.
Can anyone explain what I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your `view`.

First as you may already know, `find_one` return a single document as  Python dictionary. So in your for loop, you iterating the dictionary keys.

You really do not need that *for loop*.

```
import json


@app.route("/borough/manhattan/")
def manhattan():
    restaurant_manhattan = restaurants.find_one({'borough':'Manhattan'})
    return json.dumps(restaurant_manhattan)
```